# Touch devices (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, touch, pressure

Are there any scale on the touch inputs? I know there is sensibility settings to say if you touch or not, but does it has a scale for hard pressure and low pressure too?

If so, what scale is it? 0 to 1 or 0-255 or what possiblities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that entirely depends on the API. Android, for example, has a `getPressure()` accessor in MotionEvents that returns a float between 0.0f and 1.0f, but the actual granularity of your result obviously depends on the hardware - if the screen can only detect "pressed" vs "non-pressed", you will only ever get 0.0f or 1.0f.

EDIT: As per Julio Gorgé's answer, iOS does not offer this functionality.

Comment: Do you know if there are any Android devices in the wild that actually provide pressure readings other than "pressed" and "non-pressed"?

Comment: Intriguing question! I browsed through the market a bit and found Luke Hutchison's Multitouch Visualizer 2. Even on my old Droid, there seems to be a hit of pressure sensitivity - the circle gets bigger as I press harder, although not much. http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-metalev-multitouch-visualizer2-jjxCq.aspx

Comment: I don't know anything about iOS.

Answer (score 2):

EboMike already answered correctly your question regarding Android devices. For iOS, I can say it does not expose touch pressure information through public APIs at this moment.

Comment: thank you for adding the last details. Sorry that I cant check both answers.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add this information, but I'll give Julio a fat upvote for this information.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround for iOS. See my answer in [Tap pressure strength detection using accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179426/tap-pressure-strength-detection-using-accelerometer)

Comment: okay, sounds a bit "untrustfull" for my idea, as I think the iPad could be laying on a table while used.