# how to calculate Long Touh weight using touch?

Tags: android, performance, long-integer

friends

I want to make a new app like a calculate weight..

1) When user long press on screen i want to calculate weight of that user press weight.

2) when user touch on screen that not calculate weight only calculate long press weight..

Is it possible to get a weight using long press on devices..

i searching on a [Google](http://google.com) but not getting any output so, i decide to ask that question...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by `weight`, describe it in some words..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare like a electric weight calculate. When user long press on screen i want to calculate weight how much weight press on screen For Ex :- 1gm ,2gm,etc...

Answer (score 1):

See there are two types of touches available for mobile phones and mobile phones are distributed among these touches.

> 1) Capacitive
>
> 2) Resistive

**Capacitive touchscreen**

> Capacitive touchscreens work by sensing the conductive properties of an object, usually the skin on your fingertip. A capacitive screen on a mobile phone or smartphone usually has a glass face and doesn't rely on pressure.
>
> Some mobiles with capacitive touch
>
> HTC Desire
>
> Samsung Galaxy S
>
> Samsung Wave

**Resistive touchscreen**

> Resistive touchscreens work on the basis of pressure applied to the screen. A resistive screen consists of a number of layers. When the screen is pressed, the outer later is pushed onto the next layer — the technology senses that pressure is being applied and registers input.
>
> Some mobiles with resistive touch
>
> LG Optimus
>
> LG GW620
>
> Sony Ericsson Vivaz

As you cannot measure pressure in mobiles with capacitive touch . You app idea will not be ideal for all android devices.

Comment: Yes, but when i click on long press so,it measure some kind of weight or what ?

Comment: No you cannot measure weight.

Answer (score 0):

To detect a touch, the object has to be conductive.

It's all about whether the material used is conductive (not only human touch is copnductive). That's just how capacitive screens works. It isn't possible to detect a touch with e.g. a rock, because that isn't conductive.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515351/1405983) also helps you during your research. Also check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485586/can-i-use-smartphone-accelerometer-data-as-a-weighing-scale).